# Script blocks are supported only in .NET Framework. They are not supported on .NET Core or .NET 5 or later. (Workaround)

Tags: xslt, .net-6.0, xslcompiledtransform

I know there is already a similar questions regarding this concern but those are already at least a year old.

I know also that this functionality is still not supported in .NET6 so what I am asking here is a workaround as we are currently converting our .NET framework codes to .NET6.

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltSettings sets = new XsltSettings(true, true);
var resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();


var styleSheetUri = @"C:\Users\xxxxx\buildCardtypeProd.xslt";
//the line below is throwing an exception (XSLT compile error; Compiling jscript/ csharp scripts is not supported in .net core)
xslt.Load(styleSheetUri, sets, resolver);
```

I already tried the nugets below but it is still throwing the same exception.

1. Mvp.Xml
2. Mvp.Xml.NetStandard

Comment: With .NET framework and .NET 6, if you want to call into .NET code from XSLT, use extension objects, not embedded script blocks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-extension-objects

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to move to XSLT 3.0 while you're about it? The function library in XSLT 3.0 is sufficiently rich that you may well find you don't need those script blocks any more. XSLT 1.0 is now a quarter of a century old. [Sorry if that comes over as blatant advertising for Saxon].

Comment: Another option, if you need support for legacy `msxsl:script` but want to use .NET 6 is to use the .NET 6 version of XmlPrime https://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/download.htm.